# Stretching a Bitmap in Delphi using StretchDraw method

Tags: delphi, canvas, bitmap, delphi-xe4

I have a bitmap image of dimensions(width = 250, height = 200). I am stretching it with following code snippet, but the quality is deteriorated. Is there a way to retain the quality of bitmap image while stretching it?

```
with Bitmap do
begin
  Width := 200;
  Height := 150;
  PixelFormat := pf1bit;    
  TransparentMode := tmAuto;
  Canvas.CopyMode := cmSrcCopy;
  Canvas.FillRect(Rect(0, 0, Width, Height));
  Canvas.StretchDraw(Rect(0, 0, Width, Height), MyBitMap);
end;
```

Here, `MyBitMap` is of type `TBitMap` in which I have loaded the original bitmap image.

AND, Is this the right way of doing this?

Comment: There is no magic that you can apply here. You cannot expect the computer to synthesise pixels from thin air that maintain the quality that your human brain perceives. There are algorithms to re-sample. Which one performs best will depend on the type of image. I believe that WIC has a variety of resamplers. Another good option would be graphics32.

Comment: Adding to @DavidHeffernan's comment, The ONLY way to maintain 'image' quality when resizing is to use vector graphics...

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - Actually, I am decreasing the size of image, so I think quality should improve. I have decreased 50 pixels from its height and width. Is there any other method in Delphi which is used to decrease the size of bitmap instead of stretchdraw?

Comment: @nkp You think wrong. Any naive resizing of a raster image is liable to worsen quality. You will likely need a resampler that works well with your image type.

Comment: Imagine what you do on a small sample. Have a white raster image 3x3 pixels in size, draw a 1 pixel wide black border around and imagine resizing it e.g. to 2x2 pixels. Will that resize increase the quality ?

Comment: Try to add line "SetStretchBltMode(Canvas.Handle, HALFTONE);" before you call Canvas.StretchDraw. Then stretching should be done with kind of linear interpolation and result should look much better.

Comment: @AndreiGalatyn - This has distorted it more the previous.

Comment: The sad truth is that whenever you are resizing any raster image you are losing quality. If you are enlarging it then what you do is widening position of original pixels and you then have to fill in those empty areas in between them. most comonly these areas are filled with new pixels whose color is average of the nearby pixels. But when you are shrinking the image you are moving the original pixels closer together so they actually start overlaping (hiding) each other whihc also leads to even higher quality loss becouse you can compleetly lose any one pixel wide detail.

Comment: @nkp You are going to have to stop searching for a magic solution. There isn't one. You will need to step back and think harder about the problem. Step 1 is to think about the nature of the image. We cannot help you with that because you have not told us about the image, or shown it. Probably because you do not yet realise that is critically important. You are not going to get anywhere by thrashing around trying random suggestions without thought. Now is the time to think more deeply about the problem.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - I got your point David. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Also take note that you have changed the image from 250x200 (1.25 aspect ratio) to 200x150 (1.33 aspect ratio).  This in itself will distort the image, notwithstanding the resolution loss and aliasing which has already been discussed.  If you want to scale the image and retain the aspect ratio then you have to multiply both dimensions by the same scaling factor - addition does not work.  This is why elementary school mathematics is so important.  The correct vertical dimension for a scale to 200px wide would be 160px tall.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/borland.public.delphi.graphics/n7vFd1RJMZI) is a very nice procedure called **SmoothResize(abmp:TBitmap; NuWidth,NuHeight:integer);**. It is able to resize a TBitmap width great quality.
Don't forget to add the two type declarations.

The StretchDraw method is very fast and is a part of canvas. The quality is as you described not much brilliant. If you want to use StretchDraw change PixelFormat to pf24bit and delete the FillRect-line.

hope this helps :)

Comment: How do you think, would be ethically good to transfer the text of this procedure here in order to have a copy if the original question disappears?

Comment: @Paul pretty sure, as long as you give credit to "Charles Hacker" of Griffith University

Answer (score 0):

it could be because you have PixelFormat := pf1bit;

put it at least pf8bit or better pf24bit for better result since you don't care about the filesize